# Wipe data/ factory reset problem

Tags: recovery-mode, factory-reset

I tried to wipe data/factory reset my techno p5, but I a list of no, no, no, no, options.... I didn't see a yes option to selected to Finnaly reset my device

Comment: Welcome to the Android Enthusiasts! To reproduce your issue, it would help to know what steps exactly you have taken. What remote-wipe you are talking about? Can you please [edit] your post with a few more details?

Answer (score 1):

the "yes" option could be at the bottom and you may have to scroll to it for it to appear.